# ¿Cómo incrustar una imagen dentro de los checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Quiero poner la imagen dentro de los checkbox pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, vi proyectos pero no entiendo mucho

```css
   
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thumbnail">
  <input type="checkbox"  id="thing_5">
  <label for="thing_5">
    <img src="http://cdn2.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintar/gorra-moderna-colorear.jpg">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <input type="checkbox"  id="thing_6">
  <label for="thing_6">
    <img  src="http://cdn5.dibujos.net/dibujos/pintados/201137/3edb9367a26fe824c4a670e6367130c3.png">
  </label>
</div>


<textarea id='txtarea'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si la idea es resaltar las imágenes cuando el `checkbox` esta `checked`, puede hacer lo siguiente:

```css
.checkeable input {
  display: none;
}
.checkeable img {
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
.checkeable input {
  display: none;
}
.checkeable input:checked  + img {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkeable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cap1"/>
  <img src="http://www.primeskr.mx/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/cap-1_red.jpg"/>
</label>
<label class="checkeable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cap2"/>
  <img src="http://inikweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cap-1_black.jpg"/>
</label>
```

Explicación:

Al tener el `img` dentro del [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/label), el `click` que se realiza sobre esta se propaga al `label`.

Debido a que el `input` se encuentra dentro del `label` no es necesario utilizar el atributo `for` para decirle que esta asociado al `input`.

Luego utilizando el selector de [hermanos adyacentes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)(`+`) y la psuedo-clase [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) podemos crear una regla para que:

*"Cuando el `input` este `checked` al hermano adyacente (es decir, el 'img') le aplique algo (`input:checked  + img`)".*

Comment: es justo lo que buscaba, me das una breve explicacion porfavor

Answer (score 2):

El `checkbox` en si no puedes darle estilo.

Tienes que ocultar el `checkbox` y asociarla (`trigger`) con el elemento `label` y así poder darle estilo:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {  
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingBlue/50x50_OilPaintingBlue_6861436e56e047b38a2ffab1a3d29a4b.jpg');
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background-image: url('http://rndimg.com/ImageStore/OilPaintingRed/50x50_OilPaintingRed_5cf3b97f37c34c85adf0bc7b7eb73a55.jpg');
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, colocar la imagen dentro o junto al checkbox.

Pero podrías intentar lo siguiente con css:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}
 
input[type=checkbox] + label
{
background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/thumb-up-to-like-on-facebook_318-37196.jpg") no-repeat;
background-size: 50%;
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
{
background: url("http://icon-icons.com/icons2/936/PNG/512/thumb-down_icon-icons.com_73371.png") no-repeat;
background-size: 50%;
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label>
```

O algo con javascript y css

```js
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked')
});
```

```css
.checkbox{
    width: 23px;
    height: 21px;
     background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4p2R.png ) no-repeat 0 50%
}
.checked{
    background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4p2R.png ) no-repeat 80% 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  </div>
```